# Appropriate display not showing when user logs in successfully

Tags: python, authentication, pyqt5

I want the right window(user or admin) to show after the user logs in successfully. The program doesn't display anything apart from the landing page that the program starts with. How can I change the display from the landing page to the UserMainWindow or AdminMainWindow in my program? The code implementation in my program is not working to that effect. I hope the provided code is enough information to resolve the issue despite having removed most of the ui elements and functionality.

```
class LandingPage(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, db):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Library Management System")
        self.setMinimumSize(900, 700)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #f2f2f2;")
        self.db = db
        self.setup_ui()

     def login(self):
        # Open the login dialog here
        login_dialog = LoginDialog(self, self.db)
        result = login_dialog.exec_()

        if result == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            print("Login successful")
            
            email = login_dialog.get_email()
            password = login_dialog.get_password()
            self.handle_login(email, password)


 

    
    def handle_login(self, email, password):
        if email:
            print(f"Logged in as: {email}")

            # Retrieve user from MongoDB based on email
            user = self.db.get_user_by_email(email)
            
            if user and bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), user['password'].encode('utf-8')):
                # Valid email and password
                if user['is_admin']:
                    admin_window = AdminMainWindow(user['username'])
                    admin_window.show()
                else:
                    user_window = UserMainWindow(user['username'])
                    user_window.show()

                self.hide()  # Hide the landing page window after successful login
            else:
                print("Login failed: Invalid email or password")
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, "Login", "Login failed: Invalid email or password")
        else:
            print("Login failed: Empty email")
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, "Login", "Login failed: Empty email")


class LoginDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, db=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Login")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.db = db  # Pass the database instance to the dialog
        self.email_entry = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.password_entry = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.password_entry.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.create_widgets()

    
    def get_email(self):
        return self.email_entry.text()

    def get_password(self):
        return self.password_entry.text()

    def login(self):
        try:
            email = self.get_email()
            password = self.get_password()

            # Use your MongoDB-based database to verify the user's credentials
            if self.db.verify_user(email, password):
                self.accept()  # Login successful, close the dialog.
            else:
                QMessageBox.warning(
                    self,
                    "Login Failed",
                    "Invalid email or password. Please check your details.",
                    QMessageBox.Ok
                )
        except Exception as e:
            # Print the exception information to help diagnose the issue.
            print(f"Exception occurred: {str(e)}")
            QMessageBox.warning(
                self,
                "Login Failed",
                "An error occurred during login. Please check your details.",
                QMessageBox.Ok
            )


class UserMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, username, db=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Library Management System - User")
        self.setMinimumSize(900, 700)
        self.username = username
        self.db = db  # Pass the database instance to the window

        self.create_widgets()

    
class AdminMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, username, db=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Library Management System - Admin")
        self.setMinimumSize(900, 700)
        self.username = username
        self.db = db  # Pass the database instance to the window

        self.create_widgets()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    db = LibraryDatabase()
    landing_page = LandingPage(db)
    landing_page.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Well the program crashes after this code addition to the def login method under the landing page class:
email = login_dialog.get_email()
            password = login_dialog.get_password()
            self.handle_login(email, password)
On the console, it shows that login has been successful

Comment: Please don't add comments if you want to add info to your question. Edit the question instead.

Comment: The program does not crash. It just quits, because the last window has been closed. Both `admin_window` and `user_window` are local variables and get garbage collected as soon as the `handle_login` function returns. You should use a QDialog for the login and properly choose the "final" window depending on its result, otherwise use a custom signal and connect it to a function near the bottom of the script that will open the related window.

Comment: @mahkitah I appreciate your guidance. I'm new to using this platform.